# Optimize dataframe manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, optimization

So I want to optimize my code, which creates a new column in a dataframe(having ~10^6 rows) from columns in the df. I know, doing apply with axis = 1 is bad.
Here is the code that mocks

Here are some links i explored.

https://engineering.upside.com/a-beginners-guide-to-optimizing-pandas-code-for-speed-c09ef2c6a4d6 
https://maxpowerwastaken.github.io/blog/pandas-dont-apply-_-vectorize/ https://tomaugspurger.github.io/modern-4-performance.html

https://pastebin.com/1biaYCaW

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,500,size=(10000, 2)), 
                                    columns=list('AB'))
df['C'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(5,10,size=(10000)))
df['D'] = pd.Series(np.random.randint(1,5,size=(10000)))
df_map = pd.concat([pd.Series(df['D'].unique(), name='D'),
                    pd.Series(np.random.randint(5, 10,size=(4)), name='Map')],
                  axis=1)

def manipulate(b, c, d):
    if b == c:
        return 20
    elif c == df_map[df_map['D'] == d]['Map'].values[0]:
        return 50
    else:
        return 30

__vec_manipulate = np.vectorize(manipulate)
__vec_manipulate(df['B'].values,
                 df['C'].values,
                 df['D'].values)
```

With 10^6 rows(orignal code) takes ~16 mins.
Want to improve this.

Comment: Silly question: what does `10 lac rows` mean?

Comment: @QuangHoang 1 million rows. Indian unit of measurement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, this is `map` and `np.select` problem:

```
# this will replace the
# c == df_map[df_map['D'] == d]['Map'].values[0]
D_map = df['D'].map(df_map.set_index('D').Map)

# your return column
np.select((df.B.eq(df.C), df.C.eq(D_map)), 
          (20,50), 
          default=30)
```